# Programmatically determine available iPhone camera resolutions

Tags: ios, video, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

It looks like when I shoot video with `UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium`, on an iPod Touch it comes out 480x360, but on an iPhone 4 it's something higher (can't say just what as I don't have one handy at the moment) and on an iPad 2 presumably the same as the 4, if not something different again.

I'd like to shoot the same quality on all devices -- I have to add some frames and titles, and it'll make my life a lot easier if I just have to code that for one resolution. Is there any way to determine what the different `UIImagePickerControllerQualityType` values correspond to at run time? (Apart from shooting video with each and then examining the result, that is.)

Or is my only choice to use  `UIImagePickerControllerQualityType640x480`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get iPhone's camera resolution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638161/get-iphones-camera-resolution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need more customization/power on iOS than you get wish the higher level objects, such as `UIImagePickerController`, it is recommended to work at the next lower level: `AV Foundation Framework`. Apple has some [excellent documentation on AV Foundation programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5) that should come in handy for that purpose.

Unfortunately, even there you are limited to capturing at 640x480 if you do want it standard across all devices. There, however, is a [great chart](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/03_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5) available at the same link (but anchors are broken in the docs, so Ctrl+F to "Capturing Still Images") that lists all the resolutions for various devices under certain quality directives.

Your most solid bet, assuming 640x480 is too small, is to work out some sort of scaling algorithm that would allow you to scale according to the overall resolution.

Comment: I'm already deep into the AVFoundation docs for the writing side, so I'll keep that in mind. Missed the chart, though, thanks.

Comment: Note to future readers: Apple's moved the docs around a bit and the table is now at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW30 (still under "Capturing Still Images"). It hasn't been updated to include iPads with cameras, unfortunately.