# Future-Proof iPad Camera Resolution?

Tags: ios, ipad, camera

I'm building an iPad camera app where right now I base a fair number of calculations based on a "magic" number, i.e. the current resolution of the back 5MP camera (e.g. 2592x1936). I anticipate that *someday* Apple will replace that camera with an 8MP. Is there a way (without taking a picture and inspecting the size) that I can discover from the framework the resolution of the back camera, both now and in the future?

Thanks!

If I missed how to do that already, could you please clue me in? ;)

Comment: also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5795835/programmatically-determine-available-iphone-camera-resolutions

Comment: Yes, I read those, but if I have to recode and resubmit to take into consideration new camera models, I might as well put in more magic numbers for the new model and the older model cameras. The question is how to future-proof my code so that is unnecessary.

Comment: This one is not future-proof? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11973172/14955