# Making an iPhone 4S ***ONLY*** app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, info.plist

I have been struggling with this, but is there a way to make the app compatible with ***ONLY*** iPhone 4S (or new iPad + iPhone 4S) through info.plist or other means so that users with other iOS device models can not see and download the app on their device?

Comment: Check out this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk You can find out what device it is, and if it is not iphone 4s, dont let them use.

Comment: This wouldnt have anything to do with the 4S 60fps video capture would it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344637/capture-60fps-in-iphone-app/  I wonder if the new iPad camera shares this feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can. The iPhone 4S and new iPad are the only devices that support Bluetooth 4.0 Low Energy communications. As I describe in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8040354/19679), you can add the `bluetooth-le` key to your `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` to prevent installation on every device but the iPhone 4S and new iPad (excepting future iOS devices).

You can see the filter grid for the various devices in the [iTunes Connect Developer Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/B_DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH17-SW1)'s Appendix C - Device Compatibility Matrix.

Comment: Has anyone tried this approach and actually got the app approved by Apple? I can recount at least one case where Apple rejected the app that required a device capability (not blootooth-le) that wasn't actually used by the app.

Comment: DO NOT USE THIS METHOD. Apple will reject your app for this if your app does not actually require usage of bluetooth-le.