# The application can be downloaded from AppStore for iPhone 5 only

Tags: iphone, download, app-store

I want that users can download my app from AppStore only for iPhone 5.

I tried to set valid architecture to armv7s, but got the message

> "The key UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities contains value 'armv7s' which is
>   incompatible with the MinimumOSVersion value of '6.0'"

If I add only armv7 to "Required device capabilities" all working good, but for other iPhones too... that is not what i need.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply think its not possible because it doesn't use another architecture than the 4 or 4s and there's nothing unique like gyroscop/compass what the 4/4s don't have. This was used previously for separation. 
What iPhone5 only requirement do you have? My idea would be to write ist in the description and hope the User will read it.

Comment: You are not right about gyroscop actually, iPhone 4s support 100Hz, but iPhone 5 - 200Hz, that is not described in documentation (in apple docs only 100Hz supported), I tested it by myself, that is case for iPhone 5 support only.

Comment: Ok didn't know about this - but I'm afraid there is no public API. You can detect iPhone5 in your App and tell Users of iPhone 4/4s and previous that it's just made for iPhone5. But I doubt you can prevent them from downloading...

Comment: Although I would advise to set UIRequiredadeviceCapabilities to BluetoothLE. This is only available on 4s and 5 so you minimise the number of "wrong" devices

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382404/making-an-iphone-4s-only-app) you can use `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` to prevent installation on device.

But according to [Device Compatibility Matrix](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/B_DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH17-SW1) there is nothing unique for iPhone 5 to use in `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` to prevent installation.