# Using UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist

My app was recently rejected because it did not run on devices earlier than iPhone 5. In the app description I had highlighted this, and when the app is installed on an earlier device, a pop-up appears when the app is opened which indicates that the app doesn't work on their device. From the advice given by the review team, I need to use UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities to limit my app to iPhone 5 and higher, but I am unsure as to what device capabilities only appear in the iPhone 5 and later (e.g. how to distinguish between iPhone 4s and 5 in terms of device capabilities).

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link it may help you..

but mostly it is not possible.

[The application can be downloaded from AppStore for iPhone 5 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15827685/the-application-can-be-downloaded-from-appstore-for-iphone-5-only)