# Need quick way to identify A5/A4 devices

Tags: iphone, ios7, iphone-4

I need a quick way to identify A5/A4 based iOS 7 devices (iPhone 4S and below). I can not rely on UIScreen bounds as iPod touch 5g also has same A5 processor as iPhone 4S. I need it to determine the processing capability.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8040354

Answer (score 1):

You can distinguish devices with this code

```
+ (NSString *) platform
{
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *machine = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *platform = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:machine];
    free(machine);
    return platform;
}

+ (NSString *) platformString
{
    NSString *platform = [self platform];

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])    return @"iPhone 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])    return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])    return @"iPhone 3GS";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])    return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])    return @"Verizon iPhone 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])    return @"iPhone 4S";
    if ([platform containsString:@"iPhone5"])       return @"iPhone 5";
    if ([platform containsString:@"iPhone6"])       return @"iPhone 5S";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])    return @"iPhone 6 Plus";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])    return @"iPhone 6";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 1G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 2G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 3G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 4G";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])      return @"iPod Touch 5G";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])      return @"iPad";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])      return @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])      return @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])      return @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";

    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])      return @"iPad 2";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])      return @"iPad Mini";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])      return @"iPad Mini";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])      return @"iPad Mini )";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])      return @"iPad 3";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])      return @"iPad 3";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])      return @"iPad 3";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])      return @"iPad 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])      return @"iPad 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])      return @"iPad 4";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])      return @"iPad Air";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])      return @"iPad Air";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])      return @"iPad mini";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])      return @"iPad mini";


    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"i386"])         return @"Simulator";
    if ([platform isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])       return @"Simulator";

    return @"iOS Device";
}
```

Comment: actually I wanted to stay away from platform strings, any other compact way to figure out A5 device ?